# NiFi : Create file name using the field values from the csv flowfile

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a csv flowfile with single record. I need to create its file name based on couple of column values in the csv file. Can you please let me know how we can do it by using the column name only not the position of the column as column position may change. Example

CSV File

Name , City, State, Country, Gender

John, Dallas, Texas, USA, M

File name should be John_USA.csv

I am trying extract text processor and pulling the first data row using -
row = ^.*\r?\n(.*)

And then updateattribute processor I am pulling the values from the columns using below expression

${row:getDelimitedField(1)}_${row:getDelimitedField(4)}.csv

But this use the position of the column not the column name. How can I build it using the column name not the position of columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I will do it (maybe be not the efficient one):

- Convert the CSV to json
- Pass content to attributes (so you can access the field you want like dictionnary (key-value))
- Update Attributes
- Convert it back to CSV (thus you can control the schema, and the position of the fields).